# Multiple sweet alerts execute always the first confirmation callback

Tags: javascript, meteor, sweetalert

When i use multiple sweet alerts in the same page, it calls always the first callback.

I explain:

I have a button to send friend request which becomes a "pending/cancel" button after click

```
{{#if addFriend}}
    <li>{{> addFriendBtn user=usr}}</li>
{{/if}}
{{#if pending}}
    <li>{{> pendingFriendBtn user=usr}}</li>
{{/if}}
```

Each btn has a click event calling sweet alert:

```
Template.addFriendBtn.events({
'click .add-friend': function (evt,tpl) {
        console.log('inside click .add-friend...');
        const options = {
            title: "Friend request",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: "Oui",
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            closeOnCancel:true,
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            allowEscapeKey:true
        };

        swal(options, function () {
           console.log("Inside add-friend confirmation swal...");
           Meteor.call('sendFriendRequest', tpl.data.user);
        });
   }
}); 

Template.pendingFriendBtn.events({
    'click .cancel-request': function (evt, tpl) {
        console.log('inside click .cancel-request');
        const options = {
                    title: "Confirmation",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    closeOnConfirm: true,
                    closeOnCancel:true,
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                    allowEscapeKey:true
                };

        swal(options, function(){
           console.log("inside cancel-request confirmation swal...");
           Meteor.call('cancelFriendRequest', tpl.data.user);
         });

    }
});

Meteor.methods({
  sendFriendRequest: function (recipient) {
    console.log('Inside sendFriendRequest...');
    ...
  },

  cancelFriendRequest: function (recipient) {
    console.log('Inside cancelFriendRequest ...');
    ....
  }
});
```

When I click on "Add friend" button the first time, it works fine. I get the sweet alert and after confirmation, my callback is done correctly, and the button becomes "Pending/cancel" button.

When I click after that on this "Pending/cancel" button to cancel my friend request, i get the right sweet alert, but when i confirm, it executes the callback "sendFriendRequest" for the first button "add friend".

I couldn't figure out why it behaves like this... Any thoughts on this issue ? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:  After adding logs**

**First click: add friend:**

*Client logs:*

inside click .add-friend…

Inside add-friend confirmation swal…

*Server logs:*

Inside sendFriendRequest...

**Second click: cancel pending request:**

*Client logs*

inside click .cancel-request

Inside add-friend confirmation swal…

*Server logs:*

Inside sendFriendRequest...

Comment: Add a few console logs: first in your .add-friend event, second in your .cancel-request event, third in your sendFriendRequest callback, and last in your cancelFriendRequest callback.  Ensure that the right codepath is actually getting executed.

Comment: I added logs as you suggested (question edited) and get the following result: **First click: add friend:**

_Client logs:_
inside click .add-friend…
Inside add-friend confirmation swal…

_Server logs:_
Inside sendFriendRequest...

**Second click: cancel pending request:**

_client logs_
inside click .cancel-request
Inside add-friend confirmation swal…

_Server logs:_
Inside sendFriendRequest...

Comment: Hi, have you ever resolved this issue? If yes, how? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I too am experiencing this same issue. If you or anyone has figured this out, it'd be great if you could share the solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here..in fact I started facing the issue when I optimized one of my backend services ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just set closeOnConfirm: false in your swal config.

Answer (score 0):

tried two things which solved my problem.

1. close the first swal by swal.close();
2. add setTimeout to call the second swal